Nuxt3 $fetch request parameters from object
How to pass request parameters with $fetch ?
filter: {
  include: ['images', 'category', 'attributes']
}

get: filter=%7B%22include%22:%5B%22images%22,%22category%22,%22attributes%22%5D%7D
must: ?filter[include][0]=category&filter[include][1]=attributes&filter[include][2]=images

get: filter=%7B%22include%22:%5B%22images%22,%22category%22,%22attributes%22%5D%7D
must: ?filter[include][0]=category&filter[include][1]=attributes&filter[include][2]=images
UPD
interface InterfaceTest {
  limit?: number
  filter?: { [key: string]: any }
}
// Filter DIMANIC
const options: InterfaceTest = {
  limit: 100,
  filter: {
    category: 1,
    color: ['red', 'black']
    //....
  }
}
async function callEndpoint() {
  result.value = await $fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',{
    query: options
  })
}

// return query string parameters
// limit: 100
// filter: {"category":1,"color":["red","black"]}

// And it should be
// limit: 100
// filter[category]: 1 
// filter[color][0]:red
// filter[black][1]: bakcj

I don't understand why ofetch does this :(

Give a try to this one then: https://erikmartinjordan.com/fetch-stringify

Since $fetch is using ofetch behind the scenes, I think that you can do it this way
await $fetch("/coolpath", { query: { filter: 'images', other: '...' } });

As shown here.

Maybe I misunderstood the initial question, so here is how to consume and object and inject it into the query.
<script setup>
const result = ref({})
const options = ref({
  filter: {
    include: ['images', 'category', 'attributes']
  }
})

async function callEndpoint() {
  result.value = await $fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',{
    query: {
      filter: options.value.filter.include[0],
      other: options.value.filter.include[1]
    }
  })
}
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <div>{{ result }}</div>
    <br />

    <button @click="callEndpoint">call endpoint</button>
  </main>
</template>

If this is a regular object, you can skip the .value part because it will not be a ref.
Here is how it looks.


ofetch under the hood ruins everything :( Even if I directly give it ?filter[include][0]=category&filter[include][1]=attributes&filter[include][2]=images, it gives it as
https://prnt.sc/Uz0boNmpTYd1

@Goryyn what ??? Not sure what you want but what's wrong with my example exactly? Still not sure as of what's not working well.
